# Show multiples table results of stored procedure in c# datagridview

Tags: c#, sql-server, datagridview

```
SqlCommand Mysqlcommand = new SqlCommand(); 

if (MyConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed) 
{
    MyConnection.Open(); 
} 

Mysqlcommand.Connection = MyConnection; 
Mysqlcommand.CommandText = MysqlQuery; 
Mysqlcommand.CommandTimeout = 120; 

SqlDataReader MySqlDataReader; 
MySqlDataReader = Mysqlcommand.ExecuteReader();

bindingSource4.DataSource = MySqlDataReader;  
gridview.DataSource = bindingSource4;
```

I would like to have the datagridview as on example image:

[image]

Comment: Could you add more text? This is vague.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow,

I would recommend you to first execute this command in SQL:

```
SELECT a.Sr, a.[International Tender], a.Total, b.[Domestic Tender], b.Total,
 c.[News Automation],c.Total, d.[News Manual], d.Total
FROM
    tableA a
        inner join
    tableB b
        ON a.Sr = b.Sr
        inner join 
    TableC c
        ON b.[Domestic Tender] = c.[News Automation]
          inner join 
    TableD d
        ON c.[News Automation] = d.[News Manual]
```

If it meets your expectations I can then turn it into C# code to set it as `datagridview` source